# Return Value that doesn't Match

Tags: python, dataframe

I am comparing two columns (col1, col2) in a dataframe.  I need to compare them row by row (or side by side) to determine which values don't match.  If they don't match, then I need to return the col1 value that didn't match. This didn't work me, I got a value error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
What did I do wrong?

```
if df1['col1'] != df1['col2']:  
    print(df1['col1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing df columns returns a series of indexes where the comparison succeeds, which can then be used to index the original dataframe to create a subset.

```
print(df1[df1['col1'] != df1['col2']]['df1'])
```

Comment: Exactly. To explain further for OP's benefit, the ValueError is returned as they truly are comparing two series together; asking Pandas to return only one True/False value as a response will thus result in an "ambiguous" truth value. What they need is a subset of the dataframe, as indicated by your response.

Comment: `print(df1.loc[df1['col1'] != df1['col2'], 'df1'])` would be probably better.